# Chrome memory leak with POST with base64 encoded image in a input - how to solve?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-leaks

So, for some reasons I need to POST base64 encoded image in a input using FORM.
Size of the image ~1.1MB, sizes 2500x1700.
Base64 encoded size ~1.5MB.

So I have two inputs in the form: input file and input hidden. After downloading an image to input hidden(using FileReader to convert the image to base64), I clear input file value, so, no extra file.

When I trying to submit a form page freezes and memory consumption increases from 50% to 93% (4Gb RAM) and then Chrome crashes.

When I tried to run this page in Firefox(which is always slow and laggy) I've got instant post with no extra memory consumption.

Of course, I'll post this to Chrome issues but now I need to know: is there any tricks to avoid it? Well, maybe I'm not the first who found this bug.

---

Ok, so, if use **input.value = e.target.result** in FileReader's onload event, I get memory leak. If I set equal length custom text to input.value, there is no problem.
So, I don't think that e.target.result can save reference to FileReader(or it can?), because it's string. So we have native chrome issue on receiving FileReader result.

---

```
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("input_hidden").value = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: Are you doing a regular form post or using some ajax request? Either way show your code. And why send in base64 when you could send the file itself?

Comment: Code is too big. It's regular form post. Because I'm using input file multiple, which means user can select few files. But I need to give user ability to cancel some of images before sending. I can't manipulate input[type=file].files because it's readonly

Comment: The code "may be too big" but if you can't reproduce this in a simple example, there isn't anything we can do to help you besides guess.

Comment: Show only the code that involves your problem, you should be able to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is ajax an option? If so you are able to select which files get included to a post request

Comment: Fine x_x, take a look

Comment: have you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an invisible `<textarea>` instead of `input hidden`.

It would look like:

```
<textarea style="display:none" id="XXX">
$("XXX").value = base64
```

Also make sure to remove the `input file` completely, keep it outside of the form tags then remove it from the DOM.

Hope this helps